# Meaning of !pip when executing Python?

Tags: python, pip

I've seen an example of installing via pip that uses syntax I've never seen before: `!pip`:

```
!pip install -q tf-nightly
```

I've Googled around but the ! makes it difficult to narrow down on, what's the ! for compared with the `pip install`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is used in [`jupyter notebooks`](https://jupyter.org/) inside code cells.

It tells jupyter environment to execute BASH command instead of Python (or other kernel you have chosen).

So, this command is simply equivalent to CLI's:

```
$ pip install
```

You can use other UNIX commands from within jupyter notebook like `!ls` or `!pwd`.